# Looking up value of a specific cell subject to values in other cells

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, lookup

I have a spreadsheet I use for a game I run which involves a sheet (sheet1) which shows the players their weekly score. This is set up with their name encompassing 4 cells in the 1st row eg columns A-D and then their tally for week is calculated and shown in the 18th row cell of the 4th column encompassing their name eg column D.

I then have a separate sheet (sheet2) where all of the players weekly scores are added together which is designed with their names listed in column A and their total score in column B. I would like to have some sort of lookup in column B of sheet2 which plucks the players score from the cell of sheet1 (eg D18) based on a match between their name in column A of sheet2 and the 4 cells the name encompasses in sheet1.

I've tried using Vlookup+Match and Index+Match but not had any joy.
Is it possible to lookup a specific cell in this way?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet containing sample input, what you expect to be returned, and what formula have you tried.

Comment: Hi both, thanks for your responses. I've come up with a solution to my issue using the LOOKUP function and, although I am sure it could be tidied up a bit, it seems to be doing everything I require so will leave this one there